# Change of basis for vectors vs. for vector coordinates (Kunze 2ed, section 2.4, thrm 7)

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

Kunze's theorem on change of basis matrix refers to the coordinates of a vector relative to a particular basis. Coordinates of a vector are defined as the unique sequence (as they are ordered) of scalars in a linear combination of basis vectors which make an arbitrary vector in the space: $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\alpha_i$ where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary vector in the space, $x_i$ are the scalars, and $\alpha_i$ are the basis vectors.

My questions/confusions:

1. I do not understand how to bridge the concepts of applying change of basis to actual vectors and applying change of basis to the coordinates of the vectors. Kunze's derivation for theorem 7 actually starts with applying a change of basis to a vector, but I still can't quite connect the concepts.
2. My understanding of the final statement in the image is that the columns of $P$ are the new basis vectors relative to the old basis. But, I do not see how to prove this statement/intuitively see it as true.

3. Say we have coordinates of a vector written relative to basis $B_1$. I do not understand what it would mean to write the same coordinates relative to basis $B_2$. If we linearly combine $B_2$ by the new coordinates will we get the old vector written relative to the new basis?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is this $\alpha'_j$? It certainly does not depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: $\alpha_j'$ are vectors in the set of "old" basis vectors, denoted by script B prime in the Kunze theorem. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It does help since the notations vary a lot in old algebra books.

Answer (score 1):

The source of confusion might be this : **a vector and the coordinates of this vector are two different things**, let alone because the coordinates of the vector depends on the - arbitrary - choice of a basis. Imagine someone throws a vector space at you (not in the form of the tame $F^n$). Despite being rude, that person gives you two bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ of that vector space. Your task is, given any vector $\alpha$, to be able to express the coordinates of $\alpha$ in one basis knowing its coordinates in the other basis.

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{\alpha_1; \dots; \alpha_n \}$ (resp. $\mathcal{B}' = \{\alpha_1'; \dots; \alpha_n' \}$).

You can (hopefully that should be provided) express each $\alpha_j'$ as a linear combination of the $\alpha_i$s : there are unique elements $(a_{i,j})_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n}\in F$ such that
$$\forall 1\leqslant j \leqslant n, \ \alpha_j' = \sum_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n} a_{i,j} \cdot \alpha_i$$
In other words, $(a_{i,j})_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n}$ are the coordinates of $\alpha_j'$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ : $\boxed{[\alpha_j']_\mathcal{B} = (a_{i,j})_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n}}$

Since $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ are two basis of $V$, the unique endomorphism $f $ of $V$ that satisfies

> $f(\alpha_j) = \alpha_j'$ for all $1\leqslant j \leqslant n$.

is invertible.

In the basis $\mathcal{B}$, $f$ is *represented by* the matrix $P$ whose columns are given by the coordinates $\big( [\alpha_j']_\mathcal{B} \big)_{1\leqslant j \leqslant n}$ :
$$P = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{n,1} & \dots & a_{n,n}
\end{array}\right) $$

And here the miracle happens : the matrix that represents $f^{-1}$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}'$ turns out to be $P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at specific, low dimension, examples.
In $R^2$, $B_1$= {<1, 0>, <0, 1>} is one basis and $B_2$= {<1, 1>, <1, -1>} is another.  Vector, v= <a, b>= a<1, 0>+ b<0, 1> in $B_1$, is <p, q>= p<1, 1>+ q<1, -1>= <p+ q, p- q> in $B_2$ then we must have a= p+ q and b= p- q. Adding the two equations, a+ b= 2p so p= (a+ b)/2 and then a= (a+ b)/2+ q, q= a- (a+ b)/2= (2a- a- b)/2= (a- b)/2.

That is, changing from basis $B_1$ to basis $B_2$, we map a, b to (a+ b)/2, (a- b)/2.  In particular, we map (1, 0) to (1/2, 1/2) and (0, 1) to (1/2, -1/2).  The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2\end{bmatrix}$ does that:
$\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -1/2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}a+ \frac{1}{2}b \\ \frac{1}{2}a- \frac{1}{2}b\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{a+ b}{2} \\ \frac{a- b}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.